# Selenium and BeautifulSoup change the numbers inside html element

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the number of yellow cards each team got from the website https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/total_yel_card?se=20

Here is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/total_yel_card?se=20")
cards = {}
for i in range(1, 21):
    path = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']/td[2]/a'
    name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path).text
    
    path_card = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']/td[3]'
    card = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path_card).text
    
    cards[name] = card
```

However, the number of cards is very different than what it is in the HTML. Here is the result

```
cards

    {'Chelsea': '1,800',
 'Everton': '1,778',
 'Arsenal': '1,739',
 'Tottenham Hotspur': '1,705',
 'Manchester United': '1,685',
 'West Ham United': '1,610',
 'Aston Villa': '1,572',
 'Newcastle United': '1,534',
 'Liverpool': '1,429',
 'Manchester City': '1,409',
 'Southampton': '1,298',
 'Blackburn Rovers': '1,111',
 'Sunderland': '1,095',
 'Middlesbrough': '973',
 'Leeds United': '952',
 'Leicester City': '885',
 'Bolton Wanderers': '845',
 'Fulham': '843',
 'Crystal Palace': '790',
 'West Bromwich Albion': '769'}
```

I did encounter this problem many times too, but the numbers were generally related to currencies. However, it does not seem that this time there is any need to convert actual numbers to other numbers.

Comment: By taking a quick look at the website you linked, it seems like your program is pulling "All Seasons" data. Are there lines of code changing the filter in your program?

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the website, and it seems that your program is pulling the "All Seasons" data.

If you take a good look at the website while opening, you see that the table first shows the "All Seasons" data, before actually applying the filter.

This was solvable with adding a `time.sleep(1)`  between declaring the driver and the start of your for-loop. This created another issue, since the second half of the dictionary returned empty.
I solved this by [explicitly waiting](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the "accept all cookies" button to appear, to then click it.

Here's the code I ran:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/clubs/total_yel_card?se=20")

delay = 5 # seconds

try:
    cookieButton = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]')))
    cookieButton.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

else:
    cards = {}
    for i in range(1, 21):
        path = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']/td[2]/a'
        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path).text

        path_card = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']/td[3]'
        card = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, path_card).text

        cards[name] = card

    print(cards)
```

Here is the result:

```json
{ 'Chelsea': '74', 
'Aston Villa': '70', 
'Newcastle United': '67', 
'Wigan Athletic': '67', 
'Blackburn Rovers': '66', 
'Arsenal': '64', 
'Wolverhampton Wanderers': '64', 
'Everton': '60', 
'Stoke City': '60', 
'Sunderland': '60', 
'Norwich City': '58', 
'Fulham': '54', 
'Queens Park Rangers': '54', 
'Liverpool': '53', 
'Manchester City': '51', 
'Manchester United': '51', 
'Bolton Wanderers': '50', 
'West Bromwich Albion': '48', 
'Tottenham Hotspur': '43', 
'Swansea City': '40' }
```

Hope this helps!